# How To Submit GET Request using urllib-3 in python

Tags: python, urllib3

I'm trying to submit a get request using the following code in AWS Lambda.

```
hed = {'Authorization': f"bearer {token}"}
URL = "https://integrate.elluciancloud.com/api/academic-periods"
r = http.request('GET', URL, headers=hed)
print(r.data)
```

The Token which I'm passing is : `iLCJ0b2ciOlsiRVhDSEFOR0VfREV.TSUdORVJfRU5BQkxFRCIsIlBBQ0tBR0VTX0ZFQVRVUkVTX0VOQUJMRUQiXSwicm9sZXMiOlsiYWZlZWYyMDQtZTM3MS00MTlhLWE4OTAtOTNlNjYyMWE0MjM4Il0sInRlbmFudCI6eyJpZCI6IjcyMjJhZmEwLWYzNGYtNDRhNy1hZWVmLTEzZDE5NWJkNTQ4YSIsImFjY291bnRJZCI6IkludGVybmFsRWxsdWNpYW5CYW5uZXJNb2Rlcm5pemF`

But I'm the following error message in `r.data`

```
b'{"errors":[{"code":"General.error","description":"Application error","message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"}]}'
```

I tried to encode the token (`token = token.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`) but it's not working

Comment: You'll need to check the log on the server to find out what it doesn't like about the request.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the server code -- it shouldn't show the raw Java exception, it should do proper parameter checking and return an intelligible error message.

Comment: It's running in lambda function. Same code is working for ther url.